# Convert drawable object to int android

Tags: android

I am developing an app that shows notification .

Notifications contains images , which is retrieved from database as an byte array[] and converted to Bitmap and then drawable [ byte array[] -> Bitmap -> drawable -> int ]

I am not able to convert it to int for using it in place of `R.drawable.app_icon`

```
Notification notification = new Notification(R.drawable.app_icon,"Today's Events", System.currentTimeMillis());
```

code:

```
image=c.getBlob(c.getColumnIndex(BirthdayProvider.PHOTO));
        bitmapImage=BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        Drawable d=new BitmapDrawable(bitmapImage);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Drawable+as+notification+icon

Comment: You can not convert an object to int. R.drawable.app_icon is a resource identifier it points to a drawable object. You should use the [setLargeIcon](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.Builder.html#setLargeIcon(android.graphics.Bitmap)) method of Notification.Builder class for your purpose. In this case you can use the setSmallIcon with only resourceIdentifier, it can be your applications tiny icon.

Comment: pls also help me with this ---  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23475701/notifications-repeats-again-even-after-cancel-android